# how to validate an input from the front end , in the backend - MERN

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, mern

I have created a react app to take user inputs.

```
class VehiReg extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            vehicle:"",
            plateNo:"",
            owner:"",
            manufacturer:"",
            manufacturedYear:"",
            color:""
        }
    }


    takInput = (e) => {
        const {name,value}= e.target;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [name]:value
        })
    }

    register = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const {plateNo,owner,manufacturer,manufacturedYear,color,vehicle} = this.state;
        const data ={
            plateNo:plateNo,
            owner:owner,
            manufacturer:manufacturer,
            manufacturedYear:manufacturedYear,
            color:color,
            vehicle:vehicle
        }
        console.log(data);
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/registrations/new",data).then((res)=>{
            if(res.data.success){
                  this.setState({
                      vehicle:"",
                      plateNo:"",
                      owner:"",
                      manufacturer:"",
                      manufacturedYear:"",
                      color:""
                  })
            }
        })
    }
```

---

```
 <div className="box">
                            <input placeholder="Enter the licence plate number "
                                   className="input2" name="plateNo" value={this.state.plateNo} onChange={this.takInput} />
                        </div>
```

then I want to validate the input which the user enters.
The vehicle license plate can be in many forms:

· Vintage: 13 ශ්‍රී 9999

· Old: 250-9999, 19-9999

· Modern: WP GA-9999, CAR-9999

then according to the type which the user enters I want to write a function in the backend to validate and categorize the user inputs.
Then again I want to return the vehicle type to the frontend

the main thing that I want to know is how can I validate the user input in the backend.
here is the code I have written for entering the data into the database, before entering the data into the database that validation function should be executed.

```
//new registration
router.post("/registrations/new",(req, res)=>{
    let newRegistration = new Registrations(req.body);
    newRegistration.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:err
            })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success:"registration Ok"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl nope..! im not asking for any code. I have no idea how can I send variables or arrays which is in react app,  to the backend. Im an absolute beginner. So i expect someone to tell me the what are the areas that I should look at and study  do this

Comment: Then I suggest you study some basic tutorials on full stack validation. SO is not a "*how to*" tutorial site either. It is expected you do the basic research first yourself. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: `req.body` contains all the properties sent from front end. Start by checking `req.body.plateNo`

Comment: @charlietfl yes tanks :) i found about regular expressions also. now working on those.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of doing validations and I will share one which I have used hope this can help you.

**In Frontend:**
add properties to state:

```
    this.state = {
    plateNo: '',
    plateNoError: ''},
    plateNoValid: false,
  }
 
 takInput = (e) => {
    const {plateNo,value}= e.target;
    const plateNoRegEx =
               `^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$`
    if(!value){
        this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [plateNoError]:"Plate number cannot be empty"
      })
    }else if(!plateNo.match(plateNoRegEx)){
       this.setState({
           ...this.state,
           [plateNoError]:"Invalid Plate Number"
        })
   }else{
      this.setState({
           ...this.state,
           [plateNo]: value,
           [plateNoError]:''
        })
   }
}

 <div className="box">
           <input placeholder="Enter the licence plate number "
             className="input2" name="plateNo" value= 
              {this.state.plateNo} onChange={this.takInput} />
           {this.state.plateNoError && 
             <p>{this.state.plateNoError}</p>
           }
 </div>
```

***For backend***
you can use
1)Express validator - npm install --save express-validator
2)Joi - https://joi.dev/ - npm i joi

both are good for validating requests and you can follow the (route - controller -service) format, where you can write validations in route.

```
eg: router
    .route('/registrations/new')
    .post(validate(publicValidation.getUserByEmail), 
                      publicController.getUserByEmail)

    const getUserByEmail = {
    body: Joi.object().keys({
        email: Joi.string().required(),
        .....
    })
   };
```